# Two pagers for a single view

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have a view with fields. In fields I have added two `rendered node` fields with two different view modes `teaser` and `teaser1`.

[image]

I want to add two pagers to this view. One for the first rendered node with view mode `teaser` and one is for the 2nd rendered node with view mode `teaser1`.

I have grouped the 2nd rendered node by a date field in template file.

The first rendered node is simple a list and the pager will add new content.

The 2nd rendered node is grouped by a date field. Content is displaying under each group date. The pager for this view mode will be different.

It will add new group dates along with their content not just only content.

I have looked up for contrib module but didnt find one. I think I have do this custom. But can someone guide me from Where I should start and can give me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly this is not possible out of the box with your current setup and views only. Could you split the view into 2 seperate views instead? Use the second one as attachment for the first. So you could define the pager for each view. You could also look into [Views Field View Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view). With node specific pagers created with the [Entity Pager Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_pager) it could possibly work even with your current setup.